# Optimize elasticsearch search speed

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am working on elasticsearch version 1.7.1 using NEST, I have the following configuration:

- core i7
- 16 GB RAMS
- heap size 4GB ( I set the ES_HEAP_SIZE environment variable, but didn't check if the service is really considering it, as I found no way to check).
- 1 cluster with 2 nodes, 1 replica and 1 master, and 5 shards.
- Green Health status of the index.
- 951 indexed files

My problem is that when I search using c# and NEST for a word in the content, and specifying the size to be 951 the search is taking 1.5 secs to return about 328 records. 

Is this a good performance of elastic? or there are somethings that I can do to enhance the performance.

My other question is : How can I add filter to elastic search using NEST so I search for one field,based on another fields such as SQL query :

select * from table where field=value and field2 in (value1,value2)

Thanks,

Comment: See my answer here talking about setting up ES in production: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23280523/1173800

Comment: An observation - you probably don't want to specify the size to be 951 as this will return up to 951 records to you in one response. It would be better to paginate the results using `from` and `size` (`Skip()` and `Take()` can be used when building a query with NEST and `IQueryable`, which will translate to `from` and `size`). You will still get a total count matching the query back so that the number of pages can be calculated.

Also, could you provide some examples of the queries you are running?